# self.navigationController?.pushViewController not Working Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have CollectionViewController, when I am trying to click on cell and navigate to respective ViewControllers its not working.how can I solve this issue.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell:AddOptionCollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! AddOptionCollectionViewCell

    if (cell.name.text == "CONTRAST"){
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContrastViewController") as! ContrastViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but in this kind of scenario **never** retrieve data from the **view** (the cell), get it from the **model** (the data source)

Comment: Is `self` in a navigation controller?

Comment: Also, your `if` statement is always going to return true. I would suggest thoroughly reading the `UICollectionView` documentation before proceeding.

Comment: Also you should generally prefer the newer `show(newViewController, sender: self)` to directly accessing the navigation controller

Comment: problem get solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this problem is due to nil value of navigation stack for your  CollectionViewController class. 
So, first of all go to storyboard and select CollectionViewController class and embed NavigationController into it. After this try and run it will work.

All the best.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I mistakenly added the `MainViewController` to the `window.rootViewController` instead of adding it to the `UINavigationController` and then using the navigation as `rootViewController`.

at `SceneDelegate.swift`, it should be:

```
 let navigationController = UINavigationController()
 navigationController.pushViewController(MainRouter.createModule(using: navigationController), animated: false)
 window.rootViewController = navigationController
 window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```